# Insert Dynamic Nested JSON Data into MySQL with PHP (Laravel)

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, laravel

I'm working on a project where a JSON data feed should have any amount of columns and any amount of nested columns. So the data and structure of it is completely dynamic.
The data feed should be inserted into a MySQL database, and shown in HTML tables.

It is indeed simple to either:

1. Hardcode database columns
2. Hardcode logic for each data feed

- And those are the only examples I can find, that don't also include nested columns, or dynamic columns.

It needs to be completely dynamic data, amount of columns, amount of nested columns.

Ideally, I need to avoid repeating column names when inserting into the DB, however it seems like a tough task, considering that the "description" column is nested both inside the "channel" column, but also nested inside the "item" column

Example JSON:

```json
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "channel": 
    {
        "title": "Example.org",
        "description": "A description of the channel",
        "item": 
        [           
            {
                "id": "DK90",
                "title": "Product name",
                "description": "A description of the product",
                "link": "https://example.org/product",
                "image_link": "https://example.org/image",
                "condition": "new",
                "product_type": "Category &gt;   Category 2 &gt; Category 3 &gt; Category 4",
                "google_product_category": "a category > another category > a third category > a fourth category > a fifth category",
                "quantity": "2",
                "availability": "in stock",
                "price": "19.00 DKK",
                "sale_price": "16.00 DKK",
                "is_kit": "0",
                "custom_label_1": null,
                "gtin": "1234523006789",
                "brand": "Brand - Name",
                "mpn": "123456",
                "shipping_weight": "0.05 kg",
                "shipping": 
                {
                    "country": "DK",
                    "price": "33.00 DKK"
                }
            },          
            {
                "id": "DK91",
                "title": "A second product",
                "description": "A second product description.",
                "link": "https://example.org/second-product",
                "image_link": "https://example.org/second-image",
                "condition": "new",
                "product_type": "Cat &gt;   Cat 2 &gt; Cat 3 &gt; Cat 4",
                "google_product_category": "First cat > Second cat > Third cat > Fourth cat > Fifth cat",
                "quantity": "-11",
                "availability": "out of stock",
                "price": "19.00 DKK",
                "sale_price": "16.00 DKK",
                "is_kit": "0",
                "custom_label_1": null,
                "gtin": "1234523001123",
                "brand": "Brand - Name",
                "mpn": "123404",
                "shipping_weight": "0.05 kg",
                "shipping": 
                {
                    "country": "DK",
                    "price": "33.00 DKK"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Here is my current database setup:

[columns table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuGXm.png)
[file_lines table (values for columns)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJuic.png)

inserting json:

```php
return $this->parseFile($file_ext, $file_name, $file, $file_id);
public function parseFile($file_ext, $file_name, $file, $file_id) {
        switch ($file_ext) {
            case 'json':
                return $this->parseJson($file_name, $file, $file_id);
                break;
        }
}

public function parseJson($file_name, $file, $file_id) {
        $objects = json_decode($file, true);

        // For nested columns, currently testing
        $column_id = null;
        return $this->checkArrayRecursively($objects, $file_id, $column_id);
    }

public function checkArrayRecursively($objects, $file_id, $column_id) {

        if ($objects) {
            foreach ($objects as $key => $object) {

                $this->insertArrayValues($key, $objects[$key], $file_id, $column_id);
            }
        }

        $file_name = DB::table('files')
            ->find($file_id)
            ->name;

            return back()
                ->with('success', 'Success! The data feed was imported.')
                ->with('file', $file_name)
                ->with('btn_view_file', $file_name);
    }

 public function insertArrayValues($key, $value, $file_id, $column_id) {

        if ($column_id != null) {
            // if column has a parent column
            $column_id = DB::table('columns')
                ->insertGetId
                (
                    array
                    (
                        'column_id' => $column_id, // parent column
                        'file_id' => $file_id,
                        'name' => $key // column name...
                    )
                );
        } else {
            // of column does not have a parent column
            $column_id = DB::table('columns')
                ->insertGetId
                (
                    array
                    (
                        'column_id' => null, // no parent column
                        'file_id' => $file_id, // no parent column
                        'name' => $key // column name...
                    )
                );
        }

        if (is_array($value)) {
            return $this->checkArrayRecursively($value, $file_id, $column_id);
        } else {
            DB::table('file_lines')
                ->insert
                (
                    array
                    (
                        'column_id' => $column_id,
                        'file_id' => $file_id,
                        'value' => $value
                    )
                );
        }
    }
```

code attempt for displaying html table:

```html
<div class="table-responsive mt-5 mb-5">
                                <!-- Table here -->

                                <table class="table">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <!-- Loop parent columns -->
                                            @foreach ($columns as $key => $column)
                                                <th scope="col">{{ $column->name }}</th>
                                            @endforeach
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <!-- Loop products -->
                                        <tr>
                                            @foreach ($file_lines as $file_line)
                                                <td>{{ $file_line[0]->value ?? '' }}</td>
                                            @endforeach
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>

                            </div>
```

[how the table is displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDEF3.png)

I am not able to use noDB because my organization doesn't use that for other purposes.

Comment: Hi Alex, welcome to stack overflow. MySQL nowadays is able to work with JSON quite well: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-functions.html I would suggest to move the logic to the application which is using the JSON data from the database and just store the JSON in a LONGTEXT column. You will be able to extract values, keys, etc. with the JSON functions from MySQL that way and the full JSON will be available for apps, e.g. for your HTML producer. One way or another, at some point you will most likely be forced to be a little specific in your program code. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Tyreal.
Will take a look at it.
The reason why I can't be specific in the program code, is that the function should be possible to use for other projects in the future. I do agree that the task would be much, much simpler, if it didn't have to be completely dynamic.

Comment: My organization is against storing JSON in MySQL, since retrieving it basically breaks the database, once it contains large amounts of data in production.
Furthermore, I believe that my current solution is ideal, (See below.) since we do not use NoSQL for other products, and thus, don't want to support NoSQL only for one project.

Comment: Congratulations for finding a solution. This makes sense for your particular case. I would like to disagree that storing JSON breaks the database _in general_, this highly depends on the individual use case. It would definitely break the database if you were to do a lot of queries which need to filter by values inside the JSON, as those cannot be part of an index in mysql. For other use cases it might be just fine, even for a large amount of data.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that I have solved the issue.
This code appears to be working with completely dynamic, and nested, column names.
No duplicate columns, all nested columns inserted successfully. (Even with same name as other columns in seperate nestings.)

```php
public function checkArrayRecursively($objects, $file_id, $column_id) {

        if ($objects) {
            foreach ($objects as $key => $object) {
                $this->parentChildArr[$column_id][$key] = false;

                $this->insertArrayValues($key, $objects[$key], $file_id, $column_id);
            }
        }

        $file_name = DB::table('files')
            ->find($file_id)
            ->name;

            return back()
                ->with('success', 'Success! The data feed was imported.')
                ->with('file', $file_name)
                ->with('btn_view_file', $file_name);
    }

    public function insertArrayValues($key, $value, $file_id, $column_id) {

        if ($this->column == 0) {
            $this->column = $column_id;
        }

        if ($this->column != $column_id) {
            if (!in_array($column_id, $this->column_history)) {
                $this->column_history[] = $this->column;
                $this->column = $column_id;
            } else {
                return;
            }
        }

        if (!$this->parentChildArr[$column_id][$key])  {
            if (isset($this->parentChildArr[$column_id][$key])) {
                $this->parentChildArr[$column_id][$key] = true;
            }

            if ($column_id != null) {
                // If column has a parent column

                if (!is_int($key)) {

                    if ($column_id != DB::table('columns')->where('name', $key)->value('column_id')) {
                        $column_id = DB::table('columns')
                            ->insertGetId
                            (
                                array
                                (
                                    'column_id' => $column_id, // parent column
                                    'file_id' => $file_id,
                                    'name' => $key // column name...
                                )
                            );
                    }
                }
            } else {
                // If column doesn't have a parent column

                    $column_id = DB::table('columns')
                        ->insertGetId
                        (
                            array
                            (
                                'column_id' => null, // no parent column
                                'file_id' => $file_id,
                                'name' => $key // column name...
                            )
                        );
            }
        }

        if (is_array($value)) {
            return $this->checkArrayRecursively($value, $file_id, $column_id);
        }

        DB::table('file_lines')
                ->insert
                (
                    array
                    (
                        'column_id' => $column_id,
                        'file_id' => $file_id,
                        'value' => $value
                    )
                );
    }
```

[Columns table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54P04.png)
[File lines table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GygBf.png)

The current example only inserts one row of records, but the column insert works without error.